# Change comparison function for BST dynamically in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have made a binary search tree with the help of the following [library](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/introduction.html#sorted-list). I have made a comparison function to determine where the nodes should go. The comparison function determines the current y value for each segment.

Look at the following example:
[image: example]

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

def findCurrentY(segment):
   #uses current_x to calculate value of y...

def compare(segment):
   position = findCurrentY(segment)
   return position

global current_x
myList = SortedList(key = compare)

segments = [segment1,segment2]

current_x = 1
for segment in segments:
   myList.add(segment)

print(MyList)

current_x = 2
print(MyList)

current_x = 3
print(MyList)
```

This is how my output looks like

```
For current_x = 1:
MyList = [segment2,segment1] #y value of segment1 is higher than segment2
For current_x = 2:
MyList = [segment2,segment1]
For current_x = 3:
MyList = [segment2,segment1]
```

It shows three times the same thing, as it only calculated the compare function ones. How can I dynamically change the compare function when my current_x changes without deleting each element and adding it again to my list?

So it needs to look like this.

```
For current_x = 1:
MyList = [segment2,segment1] #segment 1 has higher y value
For current_x = 2:
MyList = [segment2,segment1] #segment 1 has higher y value
For current_x = 3:
MyList = [segment1,segment2] #segment 1 has **lower** y value
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are making a bst? Could you show how you calculate y?

Comment: Yes, please have a look at the library, it is a BST.

Comment: @PIG208 why does it matter how I calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of `current_x` doesn't alter the list as intended. That's because the whole list needs to be updated again if we change the `compare` function (i.e., to be re-sorted according to the new y values generated) and this process is necessary for this data structure.

See the below example to see unexpected results brought by using a global variable here.

```
global current_x
current_x = 1


def key_func(val):
    return globals()['current_x'] * val


list = SortedList(key=compare)
```

```
>>> list.add(2)
>>> list.add(3)
>>> list.add(5)
>>> print(list)
SortedKeyList([2, 3, 5], key=<function compare at xxx>)
>>> current_x = -1
>>> list.add(5)
>>> list.add(4)
>>> print(list)
SortedKeyList([5, 4, 2, 3, 5], key=<function compare at xxx>)
```

Apparently, `[5, 4, 2, 3, 5]` isn't the result we're expecting. Therefore,  instead of changing the key function in-place, a safer approach is to copy the original list into a new `SortedList`.

```
# Return a function that gives the y value according to x
# Segments are expected to be functions representing expressions like y=x or y=-x+4
def get_key_func(x_value: int):
    return lambda segment: segment(x_value)


# Return a new sorted list based on the same list but with different x
def new_sorted(sl: SortedList, new_x_value):
    return SortedList(sl, key=get_key_func(new_x_value))
```

So, according to the graph you gave, we can define segment1 and segment2.

```
# define y = -x + 4
def expr_one(x):
    return -x + 4


# define y = x
def expr_two(x):
    return x


# The x of the current list is 0
myList = SortedList(key=get_key_func(0))
myList.add(expr_one)         
myList.add(expr_two)
```

Then, we can try to create new list sorted by the resulting y different x.

```
for i in range(1, 4):
   print(f'For current_x = {i}:\nMyList = {new_sorted(myList, i)}')
```

The code above outputs:

```
For current_x = 1:
MyList = SortedKeyList([<function expr_two at xxx>, <function expr_one at xxx>], key=<...>)
For current_x = 2:
MyList = SortedKeyList([<function expr_two at xxx>, <function expr_one at xxx>], key=<...>)
For current_x = 3:
MyList = SortedKeyList([<function expr_one at xxx>, <function expr_two at xxx>], key=<...>)
```

However, if you insist to make the list dynamically sorted, you can implement a wrapper class in which `self.list` always refers to a list sorted as intended.

```
class DynamicSorted:
    def __init__(self, key_func):
        self.list = SortedList(key=key_func)

    def update_key_func(self, new_key_func):
        self.list = SortedList(self.list, key=new_key_func)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does the two methods have the same complexity? Or is the wrapper class much more efficient?

Comment: They are basically the same, except that the wrapper class doesn't require extra space to place the new list.